# How to fix error " 'strcmp': different types for formal and actual parameter 1 "?

Tags: c

Why do I get this error:

> 'strcmp': different types for formal and actual parameter 1

?  Here is my code:

```
typedef struct materie {
    char *nume_mat[50];
    int nota;
    struct materie *next;
} materie;

typedef struct student {
    char *nume[50];
    char *prenume[50];
    struct materie *prim;
    struct student *next;
} student; 

void adauga_student(student **lista, student *aux)
{
    student *q1, *q2;
    for (q1 = q2 = *lista;q1 != NULL && strcmp(q1->nume, aux->nume) < 0;q2 = q1, q1 = q1->next);
    if (q2 == q1)
    {
        aux->next = *lista;
        *lista = aux;
    }
    else
    {
        q2->next = aux;
        aux->next = q1;
    }
}
```

Comment: It's poor style to shoehorn the body of a `for` loop into its conditions. It is not easy to read what it does.

Comment: you need to create a [MCVE]

Comment: The arguments for `strcmp(q1->nume, aux->nume)` are arrays of `char*`  pointers, they should be arrays of `char`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This:

> ```
>     char *nume[50];
> ```

... is an array of 50 *pointers*.  That does not appear to be what you want semantically, and it is certainly not what `strcmp()` expects as an argument.

Probably what you want instead is

```
    char nume[50];
```

... an array of 50 `char`s.  That will work fine as an argument to `strcmp()`, because expressions of array type *decay* to pointers to thge first array element.  It's one of the standard forms of an argument to `strcmp`, in fact.

You probably want the same change to the other, similar declarations.